# Stream in java 8 for nested loop

Tags: filter, java-8, java-stream, nested-loops

I am trying to convert this piece of code into stream and filter but finding it really hard. help will be highly appreciated. Here is the code portion.

```java
protected void processFacetData(final List<FacetData<SearchStateData>> facets){
final List<FacetValueData<SearchStateData>> facetValueEmptyDatas = new ArrayList<FacetValueData<SearchStateData>>();

    for (final FacetData<SearchStateData> facetData : facets)
    {
        final List<FacetValueData<SearchStateData>> facetValueDatas = facetData.getValues();
            for (final FacetValueData<SearchStateData> facetValueData : facetValueDatas)
        {
            if (facetValueData.getCount() == 0)
            {
                facetValueEmptyDatas.add(facetValueData);
            }
        }
    facetValueDatas.removeAll(facetValueEmptyDatas);
    }   

}
```

Comment: If you post a [mcve] I will be able to verify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I can test the following code, based solely on the information in your question, but it looks like you need to use method `flatMap`.

```java
facets.stream()
      .flatMap(f -> f.getValues().stream())
      .filter(f -> f.getCount() == 0)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Method `flatMap` will return a single stream which you can think of as the concatenation of all the elements in all the lists of all the elements in the method parameter.

Then you filter for all the values in that stream where method `getCount` returns zero.

Finally you collect all the filtered elements into a single list.